# Are the arrangements of quarks in hadron ground-state wavefunctions rotationally symmetric?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, symmetry-breaking, neutrons, protons

The Hamiltonian of quantum chromodynamics (like the rest of the Standard Model) is rotationally symmetric. My question is whether these space symmetries are spontaneously broken in the ground state of hadrons.

The cartoon version of a hadron looks like this:
[image: https://profmattstrassler.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/nucleons2.png]

A more realistic (although still simplified) picture looks like this, showing the presence of a huge number of "sea" quarks and antiquarks:
[image]

(Image sources: https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/the-structure-of-matter/protons-and-neutrons/)

**Q1:** Do the ground-state wavefunctions of hadrons preserve or spontaneously break rotational symmetry? (I'm talking about rotations in physical space; of course a hadron is a singlet with respect to "rotations" in SU(3) color space). For a given proton, do the positions of the quarks pick out a special spatial orientation?

For scalar mesons, my guess is that the ground state is unique and the quarks are perfectly rotationally symmetric. But for baryons and vector mesons, the presence of nonzero spin degeneracy makes me wonder whether there's some kind of spin-orbit coupling that connects the hadron's spin angular momentum and the positions of the constituent quarks.

**Q2:** I know that the position of a particle is a subtle concept in relativistic QFT. But is it possible to come up with some kind of effective position density function $\rho({\bf x}) := \langle 0 | \hat{N}({\bf x}) | 0 \rangle$ within a hadron, where $\hat{N}({\bf x})$ represents a local quark number operator? (Side **Q3:** is it possible to separately do this for the "primary" quarks and for the antiquarks, or only for the total quark number operator that represents their difference?) If so, what does this position density function look like? Is it rotationally symmetric (this is a special case of Q1)? If so, does the probability density fall off monotonically with distance from the center of the hadron, or does the most likely location lie at a finite distance from the center? (Note that the most likely location is different from the most likely distance from the center, because the latter gets multiplied by a factor of $r^2$ from the Jacobian factor in the change of variables.)

Again, my guess is that for a scalar meson, $\rho({\bf x})$ is rotationally symmetric and monotonically decreases with distance, but I'm not as sure about the hadrons with spin.

Comment: I'll comment instead of answering, since I don't actually know anything about QCD. But my strong suspicion is that there is no spontaneous symmetry breaking. In general, SSB only makes sense in the thermodynamic limit, ie in an infinitely large system; in a finite system, there can be tunneling between spontaneously broken ground states, and there will generically be a unique ground state. SSB is still a useful picture in large but finite systems (ex: superfluidity in condensed matter), but given that these are $\mathcal{O}(100)$ size systems, I strongly suspect that SSB cannot occur.

Comment: @Zack I agree with you that SSB can only take place in the thermodynamic limit, but I don't think that the number of nucleons is the right way to quantify your "system size". I believe that the right value is the number of lattice sites in your lattice QCD simulation, which is implicitly taken to infinity if the continuum limit of QFT, so that (for these purposes) QFT always plays out on the thermodynamic limit no matter how many particles you have.

Comment: You might help the reader understand what you are asking if you compared your bound states to orthopositronium (so QCD is out of the picture) or the excited [χ mesons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarkonium).  A proton has spin 1/2, so it is not a singlet, if that were what you were asking, which it obviously isn't.

Comment: @tparker Please correct me if you think I'm mistaken, but I don't think SSB occurs in the continuum limit without the thermodynamic limit (ie, $N \rightarrow \infty$ while the lattice spacing $a \rightarrow 0$ such that $V$ is constant) either. Once again, superfluidity is a good example: [Mudry's textbook](https://www.amazon.com/Lecture-Theory-Condensed-Matter-Physics/dp/9814449105), for instance, has a very nice discussion on SSB in superfluidity in a finite volume of space (with continuous spacetime).

Comment: @Zack Isn't the continuum limit a special case of the thermodynamic limit? Roughly speaking, the thermodynamic limit means that the number of lattice points $N \to \infty$. As you take that limit, you can either keep the lattice spacing constant, or you can take it to zero (in such a way that the total volume stays constant or grows), and the latter choice gives you both the thermodynamic and continuum limits together.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I'm just asking whether the *position* (as opposed to spin) degrees of freedom of the quarks within the hadron - an admittedly somewhat vague notion - are correlated with the direction of the proton's spin, or are otherwise not rotationally invariant.

Comment: Spin orbit coupling? There is some literature on that….

Comment: @tparker I suppose it's a matter of terminology instead of physics, but I would consider the thermodynamic limit to mean $N \rightarrow \infty$ *and* $V \rightarrow \infty$. One good reason for this choice of terminology is that finite-size effects can (and do) occur in continuum systems with finite volume. But regardless of what you call it, it is my understanding that SSB does not strictly speaking occur in continuum field theories in a finite volume.

Comment: @Zack Hmm, my understanding was that only $N \to \infty$ was required for SSB - so that if your field theory has an explicit UV cutoff (as in condensed-matter theory) then you need to take $V \to \infty$, but if it doesn't (as is formally true in high-energy theory, although in reality quantum gravity effects eventually kick in) then you don't. But I'm not sure about this; it's a subtle topic. You may well be right. In that case, should all hadrons be thought of as in a thermal mixture of all of their degenerate spin states?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that not all systems in condensed matter automatically have a natural lattice cutoff. In the language of second quantization, or in the coherent state path integral, ordinary many-body quantum mechanics is described by a nonrelativistic quantum field theory. There's no underlying lattice scale in such a system, any imposed cutoff comes from our ignorance of high energy physics just as in relativistic QFT.

Comment: Possibly [useful](https://journals.aps.org/prc/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevC.103.045204).