Are protons and neutrons truly spherical and round like they are drawn?
I was watching a documentary "Visualizing the Proton: A Documentary"  (link)

And this image of a proton popped up. So that got me my question.
Moreover, what about electrons and other similar fundamental particles? Are they perfectly round too? If yes, why? I know gravity can't pull them to become round as it is too weak.

Why is that video on YT kids lol. Anyways check out here:- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/743570/do-protons-have-a-shape

I didn't say you're a child. I just expressed my surprise for that being in YT kids.

At the fundamental level there are no particles in nature. There are only quanta of energy. However somewhat localized "objects" can emerge from these energy exchanges. Can this be fully visualized? No, not really. That would take an infinite number of dimensions.

I still got beef with Rolf over a soccer hit at SLAC. Prolly too old for payback at this point.
